# Unable to update an angular components controller from a Jasmine test in Angular 1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine

We have a large app running on [Angular.js 1.7](https://angularjs.org/) on which we're starting to integrate [Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/) tests. I'm playing around with testing some components and ran into an issue trying to update the model from outside of Angular (pseudo functional test). In a nutshell, I'm trying to simulate an `input[type=text]` update and want the model to get updated as well.

I've distilled everything down as simply as i could. Here is the component:

```
var myComponent = {
    bindings: {},
    controller: Controller,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    template: '<input type="text" ng-model="vm.inputValue" value="" />'
};

angular.module('app', []).component('myComponent', myComponent);

function Controller() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.$onInit = _init;
  vm.inputValue = null;

  function _init() {
    vm.inputValue = 'starting value';
  }
}
```

Here is my test specification:

```
var scope;
var myComponentElement;
var myComponentController;

beforeEach(function() {

  angular.mock.module('app');

  inject(function($rootScope, $compile, $componentController) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    myComponentElement = angular.element('<my-component></my-component>');
    myComponentElement = $compile(myComponentElement)(scope);
    myComponentController = $componentController('myComponent');
    myComponentController.$onInit();
  });
});

describe('component test', function() {

  it('should update on external input', function() {
    expect(myComponentController.inputValue).toEqual('starting value');

    var myInput = myComponentElement.find('input');

    myInput.val('new value').trigger('input');

    scope.$digest();

    // this test fails as inputValue is still 'starting value'
    expect(myComponentController.inputValue).toEqual('new value');
  });

});
```

After calling `val()` and `trigger()`, the components controller isn't seeing the updated value, and the test fails. Even with `digest()` in there, it still doesn't work. I've tried triggering the update every way I can think of, but nothing. For what it's worth, click events on anchors and buttons seem to work fine, but no luck with `input[type=text]`. Any ideas?

I have a plunker with all the code and running the tests. The first test passed with the default input value, but after trying to update the value, the second test fails with the new value:

https://plnkr.co/edit/XNMaETZRuG9x74baa4Zp

Comment: I think it could be because, controller 'vm' doesn't have a watch on it and it would not update itself automatically. Is your functionality code working in real otherwise?

Comment: Don't think that's it. Everything else is working fine, and i've it using scope as well, but no luck.